# Where to session.commit() for a SELECT query - SQLALchemy, Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My application does not update the database - all queries are `SELECT` statements. I'm struggling how best to handle direct changes to the database (i.e. opening MySQLWorkbench and changing data there). Without `session.commit()`, my Flask application is returning stale data.

My solution right  now is to have a `session.commit()` as the first line of each Flask endpoint, but I feel this is the incorrect way of handling this.

Session creation at start of app:

```
engine = db.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://...')
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()

Base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(autoflush=True)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

Comment: if you're using flask, it's better to use flask-sqlalchemy as it will handle much of the work for you.

Comment: Ill look into it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`session.expire_all()` to mark all session data as expired. Then when you are trying to access something, it will be fetched from the database.

`session.expire(object)` does the same but for objects only

`db.session.refresh(some_object)` expires and reloads all object data

Nice article about that can be found here: https://www.michaelcho.me/article/sqlalchemy-commit-flush-expire-refresh-merge-whats-the-difference